# Can SQLAlchemy use the "from only" clause of PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to use the PostgreSQL **only** clause in a select query.  Can I do that with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, provided you use SQLAlchemy version 0.8.0 o newer (see [issue 2506](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2506)).

The `ONLY` keyword is implemented as a select hint:

```
result = table.select().with_hint(table, 'ONLY', 'postgresql')
```

or when using the ORM layer, on on a query object with:

```
session.query(...).with_hint(MappedClass, 'ONLY', 'postgresql')
```

Comment: Is this also possible when using `session.query(MyTable)`? Or does this only work with the SQL part of SQLAlchemy? If so, is it possible to set this globally somewhere for all tables? I am playing around with the `temporal_tables` extension and this would help avoiding accidents with `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: This works on any object that defines `with_hint()`, including a query. So `session.query(MyTable).with_hint(MyTable, 'ONLY', 'postgresql')` should work.